# How to track mouseover in a cell of NSMatrix?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nscell, nsmatrix

I would like to track a mouseover event of a NSCell in a NSMatrix. The documents say I can set the NSMatrix mode to `NSTrackModeMatrix` and the cell will be sent the message `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:` when the mouse is within the bounds of the cell, however this message is only sent to the cell when I click on the cell. I am misinterpreting the docs? If so is there another way I can use to track a mouseover event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try mouseEntered:, mouseMoved:, mouseMoved: etc.

Comment: I was looking for an out of the box solution. I guess there isn't any so I resorted to using mouseMoved and -getrow:column:point. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome. i agree, the docs could be worded better. NSTrackModeMatrix is not for rollovers, just tracking during cell selection/while the mouse is down.